# C# compiling source files as plugins

Tags: c#, cs-script

i want to make plugin support for my program

the goal is to make it compile files in plugin folder and launch
few methods but i can get it working

my current progress using CSScriptLibrary :

```
public static void run(String fileName, String methodName, params Object[] parameters)
    {
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);

        try
        {
            CSScript.Evaluator.Reset();
            CSScript.Evaluator.ReferenceAssembliesFromCode(File.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\addons\ResourceManager.cs"));
            dynamic block = CSScript.Evaluator.LoadCode(File.ReadAllText(f.FullName));
            block.Load(parameters); // <---- Exception
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

but it throws exception :

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'WAddon.Load(Weird.ResourceManager)' has some invalid arguments AddonManager.cs:line 28
```

the addon file :

```
using System;
using Weird;

class WAddon
{
public static void Load(ResourceManager resManager)
{
    resManager.add("var", "0");
}
}
```

i dont think resmanager class is important anyways want to pass instance of it to load function so it can change things on original program

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx

Comment: I swear there was a built in set of classes they introduced a while back but I can't think of it right now

Comment: @RadioSpace Did you mean MEF? https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee332203.aspx

Comment: @Koopakiller that's the one. [English](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.100).aspx) version. thanks I forgot the name.

Comment: @RadioSpace Thank you, I forgot to change the language of the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did it

```
using System;  
using Weird;  

public class WAddon : IAddon  
{  
    public void Load(ResourceManager resManager)  
    {  
        resManager.add("var", "24");  
    }  
}
```

needed to add interface :

```
using System;    

namespace Weird  
{  
    public interface IAddon  
    {  
        void Load(ResourceManager resManager, Overlay overlay);  
    }  
}
```

code from run method :

```
CSScript.Evaluator.ReferenceAssembliesFromCode(
        Weird.Properties.Resources.iaddon_source
    );
IAddon block = (IAddon) CSScript.Evaluator.LoadCode(File.ReadAllText(f.FullName));

block.Load(resManager, overlay);
```

Comment: @Karl-Johan somewhy the formatting didnt work well thanks anyways